# Bash wrapper that will format the output of another program

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there a wrapper or a method to force the **output** of another program (let's say `7zip`) inside a **bash** script to be formatted in a given way, say, **coloured** or **indented**? Or even run in a separate small graphical window? For example:

Current:

```
Welcome to program X v0.0.0
Packing file abc.xyz 10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...done
Exit. Good bye.
```

Expected:

```
Welcome to program X v0.0.0
   Packing file abc.xyz
   10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...done
Exit. Good bye.
```

Where the "Packing"... etc. is the output from this program.

Answer (score 2):

GRC (generic colorizer) worth trying http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html

By providing some regular expressions and color instruction codes in its configuration file, can have any output colorized.  Example for `traceroute` below.

[image: grc traceroute example]

Answer (score 1):

For coloring output, have a look at `ccze`, it's a log colorizer.

For indenting, you might try using `awk` depending on what you want indented and how. I don't think there are simpler tools.

Comment: Can you at least give an example?